# Yahoo Pipes RSS Icon

Tags: pipe, yahoo, favicon, yahoo-pipes

Does anyone know how I can use my own icon, that gets associated to the feed? If i subscribe to my feed in Google Reader, it shows the Yahoo logo next to it. I am using Yahoo Pipes to optimize a client's RSS feed, so it's really bad if there is the Yahoo logo, instead of the client's logo.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm also troubled by the same problem and I'm not sure if [***this link***](https://getsatisfaction.com/soup/topics/setting_favicons_with_yahoo_pipes) will help you. I haven't tried yet.